# How to implement a simple hashlock contract with initial commit of a sha256 hash of a password string

Tags: smartpy

Im trying to implement a simple hashlock contract where I initially commit a sha256 hash of a password string and an address of the target receiver.

The contract compiles and tests work (since for tests I am using the smartpy hashing procedures). But once I deploy, I can't seem to get the reveal to work since the password string that I am passing does not result in the same hash.

How should I generate my initial hash of the string so that once  the actual string is passed, the contract computes same hash?

So far I am using just a generic sha256 online generator. But I feel like smartpy `sp.sha256(sp.pack())` procedure results in something I am unable to replicate outside.

What am i doing wrong? Is the issue in encoding of the sha256? What encoding does smartpy use? Can I specify what it uses?
Code itself is here: [Link](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmdqVwgRTUS4etn2tDmyr8ZLT3tmZMmUSh5n2D2DqWgzkG&k=b0548128d548212cc145)

For example, I am trying to replicate the `sp.pack("password")`
When i convert a string "password" into hex
I get 70617373776f7264
But when I pass 70617373776f7264 into sha256 generator, I don't get the same hash as `sp.sha256(sp.pack("password"))`

So could someone clarify the correct procedure to replicate the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the pack before compute the sha256.

If you do

```
scenario.show(sp.pack("test"))
scenario.show(sp.sha256(sp.pack("test")))
```

It results in `0x05010000000474657374` and `0x5cedc49191ca9f6a0af917b23dd897c11b125970af57bd6c8f033edccf913e68`.

If you use compute the sha256, of the first result, you obtain the second.
Pay attention that `sp.pack(...)` is an hex value, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `sp.pack` adds a prefix bytes sequence that essentially says "this is a string". You can see it by doing `scenario.show(sp.pack("password"))` (output in log.txt). Instead of `sp.pack` you want `sp.utils.bytes_of_string`. Putting everything together, `scenario.show(sp.sha256(sp.utils.bytes_of_string("password")))` indeed prints the SHA256 of "password".